# How to ensure my @Transactional Spring bean gets decorated?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-transactions, spring-ws

I have a `@Transactional` service that is `@Autowired` into another existing bean.  I found that if I `@Autowire` it into another new class, the instance injected isn't the one that is supposed to be decorated by the transaction AOP advisor.  I increased the log verbosity of the `org.springframework.beans` and `org.springframework.transaction` packages and found that now my bean is being instantiated before the transaction AOP advisor.  I tried solving this by adding `@DependsOn` to it on a variety of beans that I think make sense such as `"transactionAdvisor"`, `"transactionAttributeSource"`, `"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration"`, and `"objectPostProcessor"`.  All to no avail.

Comment: Then that class is being used somewhere early on in the process (before proxies are created) and it will get an unproved instance. However without seeing code and configuration that is hard to tell.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that my bean gets instantiated only when proxies have been created?  Is there a bean that I can `@DependsOn`?

Comment: That is ensured already, unless you are injecting it in a bean that is required in the bootstrap process. So without seeing further code it is impossible to answer the question.